# How to extract the filename from blobstore record?

Tags: google-app-engine, blobstore

I save the file to blobstore with

```
af_file = files.blobstore.create(mime_type=ctype, _blobinfo_uploaded_filename=my_file.filename)
```

(yes, I know that this is depreciated, but have no other choice since Google Cloud is not available for free)

So, I have the key in result. How could I extract `_blobinfo_uploaded_filename` value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the filename and other properties from Blobinfo.
Docs: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/blobinfoclass?hl=nl#BlobInfo_properties

Example:

```
blob_info= blobstore.BlobInfo.get(blob_key)
file_name = blob_info.filename
```

You can use a blob upload as an alternative for create.